# What is the fastest way to get a random MPMediaItem

Tags: iphone, random, ipod

guys :) Can you please share some ideas how to get one or more random MPMediaItems from user's iPod Library. Any call to [MPMediaQuery songsQuery].items is waaaaay too slow - for a library of just 800 songs it takes about 19 seconds on my iPod Touch 2G to execute the query. I don't want to cache the entire iPod library, because I don't think it's worth the effort. Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this method to retrieve a random track from the music collection for my iPad Jukebox application called [My Jukebox](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/my-jukebox/id412534921?mt=8), hopefully you can use it too. Its fast, even on big music collections and if you retain the MediaQuery object (store it as a property of the class) then the second call is almost instant. I hope it helps.

```
-(MPMediaItem*) getRandomTrack
{
    // Check if we can re-use an MPMediaQuery
    if (self.mediaQuery == nil)
    {
        MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
        [self setMediaQuery:everything];
        [everything release];
    }
    // Get all Media Items into an Array (Fast)
    NSArray *allTracks = [mediaQuery items];
    // Check we have enough Tracks for a Random Choice
    if ([allTracks count] < 20)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    // Pick Random Track
    int trackNumber = arc4random() % [allTracks count];
    MPMediaItem *item = [allTracks objectAtIndex:trackNumber];
    // Display and Return
    return item;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the code! Do you have any measurements how fast is this code and for how many songs. My application is an alarm app, and I need to get random songs almost immediately (when an alarm fires), so event a few seconds delay will not work for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `[MPMediaQuery albumsQuery]` to get a random album, then try getting a random song from that album.